Does Linux support 3rd party Password Manager integration?
I'm wondering if there is a password manager API similar to how it works on iOS: You can register an application as the handler for passwords, and when you focus a password field, the iOS keyboard has a "passwords" button that will launch your desired app to search for the password for the page or app you have open.
Obviously I can install an app like KeePassXC but i'm wondering if there are any native integrations for it.

iOS (android's the same) has the advantage that the way input fields work is way more abstract than desktop Linux.
So, I'm afraid, that no, there's not a general native integration for every textbox, because "field where user enters letters into" is a less stringently defined thing for desktop Linux applications.
(I say "desktop Linux", because as said, different for Android, which enforces a completely different kind of interface to the user; it's still a Linux system.)
At least, KeePassXC has good browser add-ons that make it relatively nice to use from Firefox and Chromium. It's honestly the main place where I enter passwords manually.
